# std::string append thread safe naive solution?

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, c++11, stdstring

I want to make std::string append function thread safe, because I am appending a specific string from different threads.

I'm a quite beginner in c++ so I'm not sure what problems this may rise.

The solution I am thinking about is instead of using `somestring.append("appendthis");`

Use the following code:

```
bool appendtsReady = true;
void appendts(std::string& originalString, char* app)
{
    while (!appendtsReady) {}

    appendtsReady = false;
    originalString.append(app);
    appendtsReady = true;
}

appendts(somestring, "appendthis");
```

I would hope that if the string is being appended the new request 
`appendts(somestring, "appendthis_from_different_thread");` will be caught on loop until previous append is finished.

Is this solution is too naive?

Comment: Provide a lock for the object. Eg. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

Comment: A conforming compiler's optimizer is free to conclude that the `while` statement's conditional will never be `true` and remove that code.

Comment: Yes. Adding `volatile` to the flag might help, but a proper lock would be vastly better.

Comment: If you are "quite a beginner" you should not be writing multi-threaded code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a thread safe way. Even if `appendtsReady` were an atomic bool (if you don't change the logic)! Here's why:

Consider noone has ever written to the bool and two threads execute `appendts`. Both read the bool. Now can both read true? Yes! Because between the read of `appendtsReady` in the while loop and the write in the line below there is a tiny delay! So tiny it will work almost always, but the read of the second thread may come exactly during that delay so both read `true`.

The solution: Let them share a `std::mutex`.

```
std::mutex mutex;
void appendts(std::string& originalString, char* app)
{
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
     originalString.append(app);
}
```

Now you can call this method from two threads, provided that both threads know about the same mutex. Either declare it globally (not so nice) or pass references of the mutex to both threads.

`std::mutex` works by locking and unlocking, just as you wanted with your boolean variable.
However, `std::mutex` has thread-safety.

I recommend using a `std::lock_guard` instead of `mutex.lock(); work(); mutex.unlock();` as it provides the goodie of RAII, that is if `work()` returns, throws or breaks or whatever, the mutex get's unlocked automatically.

Comment: You could make the atomic flag version work via test-and-set. But the mutex is better.

Comment: @AlanStokes Right, what I was trying to say, that only saying "it's atomic, it's thread safe" isn't enough, because the logic would still need to be different. I've added a bit to be clearer on that, thanks!